# Preventing physical key presses from conflicting with sent keys using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to define a shortcut using autohotkey that automates navigation to the Cell Width text box in Word's ribbon menu (i.e. sends the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>,<kbd>w</kbd> while in Word).

My initial attempt at a script introduces an issue where the `Up` actions of the physical key presses haven't completed before the keys are sent by the script, causing it to fail.

Although I have a workaround (using `sleep 250`, shown further below), I would like to understand whether there is a more elegant solution - e.g. this value was chosen by trial and error, and this workaround may fail on a different machine, or if my laptop is having a bad day.

Essentially, I would like to find a solution that avoids hardcoding a wait duration.

Any suggestions?

---

### The issue

In my initial script I tried to define the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in Word, to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>,<kbd>w</kbd> in sequence. This fails and enters the text "jlw" into the active table cell instead.

This is because for keys physically pressed (marked with `#` in comments below), the `Up` actions are yet to run when the script has already begun sending keys (indicated with `$`). This disrupts the send sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>,<kbd>w</kbd> so it fails.

Also note events marked with `?` may be a byproduct of the failed actions.

#### Script

```
; Jump to table cell width entry when Alt+Shift+p pressed in Word only
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
!+p::
Send, {RAlt down}{RAlt up}jlw
Return
```

#### Key history

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A4  038     d   1.03    LAlt            #
A0  02A     d   0.14    LShift          #
50  019 h   d   0.13    p               #, h=Hook Hotkey
A5  138 i   d   0.02    RAlt            $
A5  138 i   u   0.00    RAlt            $
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         ?
11  01D i   u   0.00    Control         ?
A4  038 i   u   0.00    LAlt            #
A0  02A i   u   0.00    LShift          #
4A  024 i   d   0.00    j               $
4A  024 i   u   0.00    j               $
4C  026 i   d   0.00    l               $
4C  026 i   u   0.00    l               $
57  011 i   d   0.00    w               $
57  011 i   u   0.00    w               $
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         ?
A4  038 i   d   0.00    LAlt            ?
11  01D i   u   0.00    Control         ?
A0  02A i   d   0.00    LShift          ?
50  019 s   u   0.08    p               #
A0  02A     u   0.25    LShift          ?
A4  038     u   0.00    LAlt            ?
```

---

### Workaround

By adding a `sleep 250` statement, the hotkey and sent keys run in the intended sequence. Note no other keys are triggered (nothing indicated with `?`).

#### Script

```
; Jump to table cell width entry when Alt+Shift+p pressed in Word only
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
!+p::
Sleep 250
Send, {RAlt down}{RAlt up}jlw
Return
```

#### Key history

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A4  038     d   0.39    LAlt            #
A0  02A     d   0.20    LShift          #
50  019 h   d   0.20    p               #, h=Hook Hotkey
50  019 s   u   0.11    p               #
A0  02A     u   0.11    LShift          #
A4  038     u   0.00    LAlt            #
A5  138 i   d   0.03    RAlt            $
A5  138 i   u   0.00    RAlt            $
4A  024 i   d   0.00    j               $
4A  024 i   u   0.00    j               $
4C  026 i   d   0.00    l               $
4C  026 i   u   0.00    l               $
57  011 i   d   0.00    w               $
57  011 i   u   0.00    w               $, SUCCESS!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more elegant solution using [`KeyWait`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm). Compared to my earlier workaround script, I consider this more elegant since it doesn't require hardcoding a wait duration. This simply waits for the pressed keys to come up before the script continues, preventing any conflict:

#### Script

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
!+p::
KeyWait Alt
KeyWait Shift
KeyWait p
Send, {Alt Down}{Alt Up}jlw
Return
```

#### Key history

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Comment using previous notation
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A4  038     d   0.63    LAlt            #
A0  02A     d   0.11    LShift          #
50  019 h   d   0.11    p               #
50  019 s   u   0.06    p               #
A0  02A     u   0.19    LShift          #
A4  038     u   0.00    LAlt            #
12  038 i   d   0.01    Alt             $
12  038 i   u   0.00    Alt             $
4A  024 i   d   0.00    j               $
4A  024 i   u   0.00    j               $
4C  026 i   d   0.00    l               $
4C  026 i   u   0.00    l               $
57  011 i   d   0.00    w               $
57  011 i   u   0.00    w               $
```

---

Interestingly, the above script modified to use `Send, !jlw` works (i.e. navigates to the Cell Width box) but the sent keys come Up out of sequence as follows. I won't use this, just to avoid any unintended consequences of this occurring out of sequence.

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Comment 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A4  038     d   1.17    LAlt            
A0  02A     d   0.11    LShift          
50  019 h   d   0.14    p               
50  019 s   u   0.09    p               
A0  02A     u   0.16    LShift          
A4  038     u   0.00    LAlt            
A4  038 i   d   0.02    LAlt            <--
4A  024 i   d   0.00    j               
4A  024 i   u   0.00    j               
A4  038 i   u   0.00    LAlt            <--
4C  026 i   d   0.00    l               
4C  026 i   u   0.00    l               
57  011 i   d   0.00    w               
57  011 i   u   0.00    w
```

Answer (score 0):

If the target window does not receive the keystrokes reliably, you can try increasing the press duration in the send command via the second parameter of [SetKeyDelay](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm), eg.

```
!+p::
    SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
    Send, {RAlt down}{RAlt up}jlw
Return
```

Comment: Interesting to know this for future reference - however I want to delay the Send key, rather than extend its press duration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using right alt, don't think that's supposed to work even. Just use "Alt". And I think your hotkey is not very good for this. Word gets confused with the input.
But I think maybe doing this, could work

```
!+p up:: ;up means it'll run once u release p, might help a bit
    SetKeyDelay, 500, 10 ;good amount of delay, can probably do with less
    Send, {Shift Up}{Alt Up}{Alt}jlw ;send shift and alt up first
Return
```

And now for a better alternative option, automating it with the [Word ComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application). Usage of [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) for this is the *normal* and intended way, but you can AHK (or any other language) just as well.
Here's a quick AHK example of changing the first table's first cell's width:

```
Word := ComObjActive("Word.Application")
Word.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Width := 500
```

Of course that's not a very good way to go about this, I'm sure you can reference the active table and active cell somehow, I just quickly read the docs and wrote that. Haven't actually ever used any of this stuff in practice myself.

Comment: I'm using RAlt only to distinguish it from LAlt in the key history while I troubleshoot. On my machine, it works just as effectively for this purpose. In the meantime though I've found an solution that I'll post shortly, which I find more elegant as it avoids hardcoding a wait duration.